# Trying to clone a gem and git fetch/merge all pull requests but merge fails

Tags: git, github, merge, clone

I'm trying to get the forgery gem with the entire package including all pull requests.  In the end, the merge fails.  Is what I am trying to do possible?  If so, what do I need to do beyond what is shown here?

```
D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12\projects>git clone https://github.com/sevenwire/forgery.git
Cloning into 'forgery'...
remote: Counting objects: 1472, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (760/760), done.
Receiving objects:  99% (1458/1472)
Receiving objects: 100% (1472/1472), 390.22 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (744/744), done.

D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12\projects>cd forgery

D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12\projects\forgery>git config --local remote.origin.fetch "+refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/or
igin/pr/*

D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12\projects\forgery>git config --local --add merge.defaultToUpstream true

D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12\projects\forgery>git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 502, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (225/225), done.
Receiving objects:  85% (324/381)    299 (delta 150)
Receiving objects: 100% (381/381), 107.79 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (224/224), completed with 48 local objects.
From https://github.com/sevenwire/forgery
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/10/head -> origin/pr/10
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/11/head -> origin/pr/11
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/12/head -> origin/pr/12
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/13/head -> origin/pr/13
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/15/head -> origin/pr/15
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/17/head -> origin/pr/17
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/18/head -> origin/pr/18
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/19/head -> origin/pr/19
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/21/head -> origin/pr/21
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/22/head -> origin/pr/22
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/23/head -> origin/pr/23
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/24/head -> origin/pr/24
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/25/head -> origin/pr/25
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/26/head -> origin/pr/26
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/27/head -> origin/pr/27
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/29/head -> origin/pr/29
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/31/head -> origin/pr/31
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/32/head -> origin/pr/32
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/34/head -> origin/pr/34
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/39/head -> origin/pr/39
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/40/head -> origin/pr/40
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/41/head -> origin/pr/41
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/45/head -> origin/pr/45
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/49/head -> origin/pr/49
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/50/head -> origin/pr/50
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/51/head -> origin/pr/51
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/52/head -> origin/pr/52
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/56/head -> origin/pr/56
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/57/head -> origin/pr/57
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/58/head -> origin/pr/58
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/59/head -> origin/pr/59
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/60/head -> origin/pr/60
 * [new ref]         refs/pull/9/head -> origin/pr/9

D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12\projects\forgery>git merge
fatal: No remote tracking branch for refs/heads/master from origin

D:\BitNami\rubystack-1.9.3-12\projects\forgery>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working through this, I devised a method of attempting to install all pull requests (PR's) using captures and scripts.  I found that wasn't necessarily a wise thing to do.  The PR's often have conflicts.  So, I decided that I need to select which PR I want on an individual basis and built this script, where %1 is the PR that I want installed:

```
git checkout pr/%1
git checkout master
git merge pr/%1
```

This is all after running the process specified in the original question, save for the git merge.